# Python PIL PhotoImage image "pyimage1" doesn't exist when subclassing Tk

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to programmatically scan a directory and display all the images in that directory. However, every time I try to add an image to a Button widget, I keep on getting the `image "pyimage1" doesn't exist` error. I have tried to assign an object reference to the Button, but it doesn't fix it. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
class App(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, directory):
        super().__init__()
        self.directory = directory
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        for image in filter(lambda name: name.endswith(".jpg"), os.listdir("images")):
            img = open(os.path.join(self.directory, image)).resize((320, 180))
            image_obj = PhotoImage(img)
            button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text=image, command=lambda: do_something(image))
            button.image = image_obj
            button.configure(image=image_obj)
```

Comment: It is most properly due to multiple instances of `Tk()`.

Comment: You've left out some critical details, as this code shouldn't even run (where does `self.frame` come from?).

Comment: Actually OP code has several issues, like `os.listdir("PATH")`, `self.directory` not defined, etc.

Comment: please provide a complete [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are subclassing the Tk object, try making the class be the master of the Button object.

```
class App(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for image in filter(lambda name: name.endswith(".jpg"), os.listdir("PATH")):
            img = open(os.path.join(self.directory, image)).resize((320, 180))
            image_obj = PhotoImage(img, master=self)
            button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text=image, command=lambda: None)
            button.image = image_obj
            button.configure(image=image_obj)
```